# Adding an index on tag value with XSLT: `position()` returning double the expected value

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have an input XML:

```
<root>
<child>somevalue</child>
<child>othervalue</child>
</root>
```

And a need this output:

```
<root>
<child>item1_somevalue</child>
<child>item2_othervalue</child>
</root>
```

I'm using this template:

```
<xsl:template match="*[local-name()='root' and namespace-uri()='']/*[local-name()='child' and namespace-uri()='']">
<xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
<xsl:text>item</xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="position()"/>
<xsl:text>_</xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

And getting this result:

```
<child>item2_somevalue</child>
<child>item4_othervalue</child>
```

Why is `position()` returning double the expected value?

I'm not worried about the root tag right now.

Must use XSLT 1.0.

Comment: This seems to be a trivial task: use the `position()` function.

Comment: ... but *the question*, as presented, is too broad.

Comment: I edited the question with an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Explaining what's going on

The `position()` function can return unexpected results sometimes.  At first glance, it sounds like it should return the position of the context element with respect to its parent container.  So for our sample input XML:

```
<root>
    <child>somevalue</child>
    <child>othervalue</child>
</root>
```

... we would expect to see that the `position()` for the first `child` element would be `1`, and the `position()` for the second `child` element would be `2`.

But when we run our sample XSL against that code, we get the following output:

```
<child>item2_somevalue</child>
<child>item4_othervalue</child>
```

**The key is** that we need to pay special attention to the wording.  The `position()` element doesn't just count *elements*, it counts *nodes* -- and that **includes** text nodes.  So in the sample input XML above, the first `child` element is actually the **second** node under `root`, because it's preceded by a text node (the newline and leading whitespace).  And, for the same reason, the second `child` element is actually the **fourth** node under `root`.  So `position()` is returning exactly what it should.

### Fixing the behavior

There are a couple ways of fixing this.  One is to explicitly count `child` elements, as jpmo22's post does.  Another approach, which is more flexible, is to tell the XSL processor to ignore whitespace-only text nodes.  We can do this by adding a top-level element to our XSLT code:

```
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
```

We can customize the list of elements if needed, by replacing the `*` with a list of element names.

If we just add that `strip-space` directive before the `template` in our sample XSL code, we can get the expected result:

```
<child>item1_somevalue</child>
<child>item2_othervalue</child>
```

#### Other considerations

- The XPath in the `match` statement is convoluted.

  ```
  <xsl:template match="*[local-name()='root' and namespace-uri()='']/*[local-name()='child' and namespace-uri()='']">
  ```

  In cases where element names have no prefixes, `local-name` and `name` return identical results.  Our sample input XML has no prefixes, so there's no reason to use `local-name`.  In fact, we could simply use the desired element names rather than `*`.  Moreover, our sample input XML has no namespace declarations at all, so there's no reason to use `namespace-uri`.

  A suggested simplification:

  ```
  <xsl:template match="root/child">
  ```
- The use of `element` is also a bit convoluted.

  ```
  <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
  ```

  We already know that we're working with `child` elements, since that's what we just `match`ed in this template.  We could more simply just use the element name in a literal element declaration, like this:

  ```
  <child>
  ```

  If we wanted to genericize our code, we could also just copy over the context element:

  ```
  <xsl:copy>
  ```

Comment: Thank you for a very complete answer and explanation. About "Other consideration" topic I simplified my actual XSLT wicth I need to use an especific name-space and thats why the match seens to be convoluted. On my real XSLT I don't know if the name of the tag is "child" but your consideration is valid for the example I gave. Use the strip-space directive didn't work on my real XSLT I'm assuming is because it's more complex and have another templates running.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. I changed the `position()` to `count(preceding::*[local-name()='child']) + 1`

XSLT:

```
<xsl:template match="*[local-name()='child']">
<xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
<xsl:text>item</xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="count(preceding::*[local-name()='child']) + 1"/>
<xsl:text>_</xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

Gives the right result:

```
<child>item1_somevalue</child>
<child>item2_othervalue</child>
```

Comment: Repeatedly counting preceding siblings is expensive. A better solution is to control the selected node-set, for example by stripping white-space-only nodes or by applying templates only to `child` elements from the context of a template matching `root`.